# How to display Banner in list page dynamically?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community

I want to keep banner images in list page. Creating a `static block` for that and selecting that `static block` for each category will work and I tried that. But I have more number of categories & subcategories like 50+. So should I create a `static block` for each and every category or is there any way to fetch that banner images dynamically?

Comment: have you tried with creating new category attribute, (WYSIWYG) type ? Also what's `banner images` here ? Are they from any extension ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a widget and assign widget to particular categories hope this will help you.